# fix table header with rowspan and colspan property and scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make a table header fix to one position and allow the remaining content of table to be scrollable(code below). I am using colspan and rowsapn property in the table header row . Is there any way to fix it ?

```
<html>
   <body> 
   <div id="secondtable" style="width:100%; height:380px; overflow:auto;">
   <table class="mytable" style="width:100%; border-width:thin;" border="1"      cellpadding="9" cellspacing="0" align="center">    
                <tr class="tt" bgcolor="#0B2B62">
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Store Name</th>
                    <th>Receipts</th>
                    <th colspan=2>Receipts vs Budget</th>
                    <th colspan=3>Receipts vs Last Year</th>
                    <th>Contribution</th>
                    <th colspan=2>Contribution vs Budget</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tt" style="background-color:#C2C2C2;">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><font color="black">Var &pound;</font></td>
                    <td><font color="black">Var %</td>
                    <td><font color="black">Var &pound;</font></td>
                    <td><font color="black">Var %</font></td>
                    <td><font color="black">Var</font></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><font color="black">Var &pound;</font></td>
                    <td><font color="black">Var %</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tt" style="background-color:#D7F2FF">
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

//this is css

```
table {

border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing: 0;
color:white;
background-color:white;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}

.mytable{
background-color:#014483;
}

.tt{
border-color:#2B4F81;
}
.ttt{
background-color:#BBDBF4;
border:#2B4F81;
}
```

Comment: see the demo here how i want- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/1049/

Answer (score 3):

Question of 3 years old,however for those who still have no solution for this (table head with rowspan) I finally have the methode using js.

```
<div id="table">
 <table>
   <thead>
     <!-- your head code -->
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <!-- your body code -->
   </body>
 </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#table{
    height:200px; //for example 
    overflow-y:auto; 
}
```

JS

```
let statusCard = document.querySelector('#table');
    // add scroll event listener for change head's position 
    statusCard.addEventListener('scroll',e =>{
      let tableHead = document.querySelector('thead');
      let scrollTop =  statusCard.scrollTop;
      tableHead.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollTop + 'px)';
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
.mytable tr th
{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: i want to keep table header fix and the remaining table content should be scroll able. the problem in my code is the whole table is scrolling with header too, whereas i want to keep the table header to be at its place

Comment: .mytable tr th
{
table-layout: fixed;
} you can use it

Comment: no help with this question @Anubhavpun, the question is "With ROWSPAN/COLSPAN"... in your exemple there is no rowspan or colspan.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to place your header in a div with a class `.sticky` or whatever you like and a proper CSS.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="sticky">
  <table class="mytable" style="width:100%; border-width:thin;" border="1" cellpadding="9" cellspacing="0" align="center">
      <tr class="tt" bgcolor="#0B2B62">
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Store Name</th>
        <th>Receipts</th>
        <th colspan=2>Receipts vs Budget</th>
        <th colspan=3>Receipts vs Last Year</th>
        <th>Contribution</th>
        <th colspan=2>Contribution vs Budget</th>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2px;
  width: 96.5%;
}
```

See the example here: http://codepen.io/omerblink/pen/wMzLow?editors=110

Comment: thanks....but it not in a proper align...i want to fix that which is most imp for me,,,as i have used rowspan and colspan into it

Comment: Ok I have updated the question and the pen ... Can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Tried my best :((((((((((((

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will be able to acheive this with a single table. So I have actually created two tables one for header and another for body & the former is always fixed. Also I assume that number of columns is static. Here is the code

```
<!--Header part-->    
<div id="firsttable" style="width:100%;">
        <table class="mytable" style="width:100%; border-width:thin;" border="1" cellpadding="9" cellspacing="0" align="center">
          <thead><tr class="tt " bgcolor="#0B2B62">

            <th id="no">No.</th>
            <th id="sto">Store Name</th>
            <th id="res">Receipts</th>
            <th colspan=2 id="rb">Receipts vs Budget</th>
            <th colspan=3 id="rl">Receipts vs Last Year</th>
            <th id="con">Contribution</th>
            <th colspan=2 id="cb">Contribution vs Budget</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          </table>
          </div>

<!-- body part -->

    <div id="secondtable" style="width:100%; height:380px; overflow:auto;">
              <table class="mytable" style="width:100%; border-width:thin;" border="1" cellpadding="9" cellspacing="0" align="center">

              <tr class="tt" style="background-color:#C2C2C2;">
                <td headers="no">A</td>
                <td headers="sto">B</td>
                <td headers="res">C</td>
                <td colspan="2" headers="rb"><div style="color:black">Var &pound;</div><div style="color:black">Var %</div></td>
                <td colspan="3"><div style="color:black">Var &pound;</div><div>Var %</div><div>Var</div></td>
                <td>D</td>
                <td colspan="2"><div style ="color:black">Var &pound;</div><div style="color:black">Var %</div></td>
              </tr>

              <!-- Include multiple tr to get scrollbar -->
            </table>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
table {
border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing: 0;
color:white;
background-color:white;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}

.mytable{
background-color:#014483;
}

.tt{
border-color:#2B4F81;
}
.ttt{
background-color:#BBDBF4;
border:#2B4F81;
}

td,th{
    max-width:10px;

    }
.mytable div{
    max-width:40%;
    display:inline
    }
```

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/tvkeypxk/11/)

**NOTE**:When this scrollbar is visible you may see that the header columns is not in sync with body columns. This is because scroll bar has a width and it is will occupy some space.In this case you can adjust the width of any body column so that it is in sync. Also I understand basically you need 7 columns there can be subcolumns. So in body I have created 7 columns and div  to replicate the sub columns

Hope this will be helpful